Using Llama_index with Mistral Model
I'm new to the field of large language models (LLMs), so I apologize if my explanation isn't clear.
I have a Mistral model running in a private cloud, and I have both the URL and the model name.
URL = " http://mistral...../v1/chat/completions"
Model = "Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2/"
I need to build a chatbot using LlamaIndex based on our Mistral LLM. All the code I find in the documentations requires an API Key, which I don't have.
from llama_index.llms.mistralai import MistralAI
llm = MistralAI(api_key = api_key, model = model)

I'm a bit confused about whether it's possible to use LlamaIndex witout API Key. Should I use a function call instead? What exactly is the process I need to follow?

I do not know whether you can use it without API key.
My assumption is you cannot.
However, you can run Mistral locally using ollama.
Run ollama pull mistral (source) or ollama pull mixtral (source).
Then serve the model using Ollama.
Ollama(model="mistral", request_timeout=120.0)

There is an example in the documentation using Llama3.
You should be able to apply it to your scenario.
